# Android Market Account registration and Google Checkout Merchant registration with two different acounts

Tags: android, google-play, google-checkout

I am about to create Android Market Account. Lets say I have two accounts, account A and account B.

1. Can I use account A to pay android market registration fee of 25$ ?
2. Can I use account B to get money on sale of my app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Google Play support site](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139626):

> At this time, Google Play Android Developer account and the Google Checkout Merchant account must be the same Google Account address.

However, depending on your needs, you may well be satisfied with the workaround I use:

1. Use account A to register and pay the $25 fee.
2. Add account B as a "Full Access" user in your Google Checkout settings.

Technically that satisfies both of your requirements, with the caveat that *both* accounts can access Google Checkout.